# Visiting relatives in UK - access to country dependent on their finances?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I want to visit my mother in the UK, she is hesitant to send in the invitation letter cause she does not make much of a salary and they may refuse me to stay with her. Can they refuse me to stay with her seeing as she may not have that much money?

Comment: Hi morgan! We need a little bit more information. You should at least reveal your citizenship.

Comment: How long do you want to visit?

Comment: Who is "they"? The border people can't prevent your mother from hosting you, they can however prevent you from entering the country. Usually the finances of the person you're visiting are only relevant for multi-year visits, not for short ones. Give us more information about your plans...

Comment: @KateGregory Judging by a necessity for a letter of invitation I would assume the "they" are actually consular workers responsible for issuing a visa.

Comment: Hi Morgan.  As you can see above, there's quite a bit of information people need to answer your question properly.  I've also edited the title to make it a bit clearer.  Please can you edit your question with the extra information requested, so that we can help you out with some answers!

Comment: Haven't had a response, so I'm closing.  Morgan - if you come back, please do edit your question and flag to reopen.  As you can see, many people were keen to help, but there was information missing that we needed in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of anyone being denied passage to a country because the person they were visiting had limited resources.

Yourself however may be a factor. You need sufficient resources to provide for your stay in all countries visiting. Other then that you should be good to go.

Comment: Unless she provides for him. I think that's the OP's case.

Comment: Ah, that's a different case. Wasn't sure how old OP is and whether they were financially independent. @HaLaBi